# Azure Stream Analytics - no input events when using refrence data

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

My Azure Stream Analytics Job does not detect any input events if I use **reference data** in the query. When I'm using **only streaming data it works well**. 
Here is my query:

```
SELECT v.localization as Station, v.lonn as Station_Longitude, v.latt as Station_Latitude, d.lat as My_Latitude, d.lon as My_Longitude
INTO [closest-station]
FROM eventhub d
CROSS JOIN [stations] v 
WHERE ST_DISTANCE(CreatePoint(d.lat, d.lon), CreatePoint(v.latt, v.lonn) ) < 300
```

I used eventhub and blob as the input and the result was the same - works only without reference data

Inb4

- When I'm testing the query with sample reference data (I'm uploading the exact same file as stored in the reference data location) it returns expected values
- I've tested both inputs and tests were conducted successfully
- The data comes from the logic app which copies it from dropbox to the eventhub or storage account (I've tested both scenarios) that are used in Azure Stream Analytics as inputs. Even if see this ran successfully, still no input events in ASA appear.

The idea is to get coordinates of the stations closer than 300 m to my localization.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, will do as you advised.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** - you have to specify explicitly the reference file in the reference data input path pattern. Specifying container only doesn't work even if there is only one file inside.

> Stream Analytics job will wait indefinitely for the blob to become available

As described here: [Use referenece data for lookups in Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data)